# How to serve ReactJS static files with expressJS?

Tags: reactjs, express, static, server, create-react-app

## The Problem

I have successfully served the index.html file of my React app, but the `index.js` that replaces `<root>` in the html file
with my first React component is not triggering on `ReactDOM.render`.
*How do I get the `index.js` file to start?* If my understanding of serving a React app is skewed in certain ways, I would greatly
appreciate clarification.

### Folder Structure

- / - contains all server-side files, including `server.js`
- /client/ - contains all React files
- /client/build/ - contains all production-ready client files

  - /client/build/`index.html`
  - /client/build/static/js/`main.[hash].js` - seems to be a minified version of `index.js` that contains the `ReactDOM.render` for
    my React app

### Current Deployment

- I am using Facebook's create-react-app for the /client/ directory, including npm run build to automatically populate /client/build/

### File Snippets

```
// server.js
let app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/public')));
```

This successfully loads the default index.html provided by
create-react-app

```
// index.html
<body>
  <noscript>
    You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
  </noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

The above section of code may/may not be useful, but it is the default
html file that comes with create-react-app. Do I need to replace the
noscript tag with a script tag that references the minified `index.js`
file? I have attempted that, and nothing changed, but perhaps it is
because of incorrect relative path-making.

Comment: https://github.com/mInzamamMalik/Serving-ReactJS-web-application-in-express.js-static-file-hosting
this code example may help, feel free to comment

Answer (score 34, accepted):

After trying many different things through trial/error, the solution is quite simple:

Serve the /client/build folder in the static call, like so:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build')));
```

Comment: Care to explain why this work because if you see in your folder structure there might be no client/build folder

Comment: It works after you build the client site with `npm run build`. You have to serve the client code generated and cross-linked by React instead of the `public` folder that you work on.

Comment: And how to get "/" path

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem for a while and I would say that the solution that works is divided into 2 parts to avoid problems with the routers

1. Server the static from the CRA build (in your case the client/build)

```js
const buildPath = path.normalize(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build'));
app.use(express.static(buildPath));
```

2. Set a final route (after all other routers in your server) to use the following:

```js
const rootRouter = express.Router();
/* 
* all your other routes go here
*/
rootRouter.get('(/*)?', async (req, res, next) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(buildPath, 'index.html'));
});
app.use(rootRouter);
```

Answer (score 0):

//on your react app run

```
npm run build
```

//The insert the following code on your server

```
const path = require("path");
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"nameOfYourReactApp","build")))

//Replace nameOfYourReactApp with the name of your app
```

Answer (score 0):

my project structure
project
-->client
back end(express)\

after using npn run build i found out that index.html in build was using wrong directory of css files or static instead of using

```js
const path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client/build/')));
```

i know i also tried ../client...... but not working

so what i did is cut and paste static folder of build in root directory this image can give you the idea, and its working [structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkXuT.png)