# Static react app can't navigate or refresh other than / url

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I created my react app with create-react-app and I built it with the `yarn build`. Then I am using Express js server to render the static react app. My react app is using react router. When I try navigate to the url, it gives me 404. Also refresh gives me the same result. It makes sense the build react app does not have the "paths", i.e. there is no "hello" folder for "/hello". How do I resolve this?

This is how I serve the static react app in Express js. `app.use(express.static('public'));`
`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that replicates the behavior you are asking acting.

Comment: can u try solutions from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44684461/how-to-serve-reactjs-static-files-with-expressjs specifically the second one

Answer (score 0):

## React Router DOM

React handles its own routing system [`react-router-dom`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom) you won't need express.

And checkout newest documentation if you're using latest package version.
[`documentation`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial)

In your terminal, use npm to install the package:

```
npm install react-router-dom
```

or yarn

```
yarn add react-router-dom
```

> This sample code is just to get a sketch idea about the react-router-dom. Please read the latest [`documentation`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial)

> react-router-dom version 5.x.x

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <h1>APP.JS</h1>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/page1">
            <page1 />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/page2">
            <page2 />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/page3">
            <page3 />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to use this

[React Router Dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom)

you can also check my personal wireframe it is still under process but you get the idea

[REPO](https://github.com/Bhrugu14/react-wireframe)
[Live Link](https://react-vite-wireframe.vercel.app/)